# Simple Select from MySQL with PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql

i know this is really noob question but iam starting with MySQL. I have this table:

[image]

Now i want take opcja_value and do simple PHP if statment:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  `opcje` WHERE ( `opcje`.`ID` =2 )";
$minifier = $conn->query($sql);

if ( $minifier['opcja_value'] == 1 ) {
    echo 'opcja value is 1';
} else {
        echo 'opcja value is other number than 1';
}
```

I want take opcja_value number

Comment: You're asking about a simple select not working, but I don't actually see a select query in the code you posted. Did you forget to add part of your code?

Comment: Yes i try do this with below code:

Comment: If you're going to add that code, please **[edit]** your question rather than putting it in a comment.

Comment: I update code, i try take opcja_value from ID 2 tehn check if this number is equal to 1

Comment: It looks like the main problem there is that you aren't fetching a result after you run your query. Are you using pdo or mysqli?

Comment: i was looking for this: SELECT `opcja_value` FROM `opcje`
WHERE `opcja_name`='minifier';

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you used `` inside your query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  opcje WHERE ID=2";
$minifier = $conn->query($sql);

if ( $minifier['opcja_value'] == 1 ) {
  echo 'opcja value is 1';
} else {
    echo 'opcja value is other number than 1';
}
```

I hope you placed your connections properly.